# jQuery/JS splice() not working on object array

Tags: arrays, object, splice

I'm having trouble getting a splice to work.

I have an array, that I push objects into...

one of the 'properties' on these objects Im pushing is an array  (with me so far?):)

quick example:

```
var userPicks = [];

userPicks.push({casename:caseName, fullname:fullName, trialdate:trialDate, citystate:cityState, plaintiff:plaintiff, itemsordered:itemsOrdered=[{name:itemOrdered, price:itemPrice}]});
```

this all works fine and dandy...  I can push things in.. access them and see the correct data in console  (FireBug)

but when I try to splice something.. I get an error in FireBug/console..

```
TypeError: userPicks[i].itemsordered[x].splice is not a function
```

However, I can add things to the 'sub-array' (I'll refer to it as...the itemsorderd[x] array)..   access/read them as well...??

```
console.log("Name Check: "+userPicks[i].itemsordered[x].name);  //works

userPicks[i].itemsordered.push({name:itemOrdered, price:itemPrice}); //works
```

but the splice isnt working?

What am I missing?  syntax error somehow?

PLEASE!,, only answer if you want to provide 'help'.. not to just inform me your dont know or have time to help.

I cant seem to SPLICE() the array that is in the object property.. (although pushing, and accessing/read to same array is fine)

all 'real' help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call splice on an object not an array:

- `userPicks[i].itemsordered` is the array
- `userPicks[i].itemsordered[x]` is an object inside the array, not an array itself.

You want to call splice on `userPicks[i].itemsordered`, i.e:

```
userPicks[i].itemsordered.splice(...)
```

Comment: ahh..   you are correct!  works great, thanks for the tip!  (ANSWER ACCEPTED)